# Differentiate $(x + 1)(x + 2)^2(x + 3)^3$

Tags: calculus

Obviously we can "brute force" this by multiplying the various terms and differentiating from there. But based upon the solution provided in the text where I found this problem, it looks like there's a "cleaner" method available.

Of note, this problem appears in the chapter introducing the chain rule.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: just to clarify, this problem appears in a very basic calculus text, so any/all "advanced" differentiation techniques would not be at the student's disposal. It's also worth pointing out the answer provided in the text:

$2(x + 2)(x + 3)^2(3x^2 + 11x + 9)$

Comment: It's the product of three functions, namely $(x+1)$,$(x+2)^2$, and $(x+3)^3$, each of which has an easy derivative to compute using the chain rule, so I would use the product rule.

Comment: If you're interested, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160924/using-the-product-rule-to-show-that-fgh-f-gh-fg-h-fgh/1161032#1161032) is a proof of the generalized product rule vadim123 references that I provided a while back.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend the [extended product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#A_product_of_more_than_two_factors) which states that $$(fgh)'=(f')(gh)+(g')(fh)+(h')(fg)$$

For this particular problem, $f=(x+1), f'=1$, $g=(x+2)^2, g'=2(x+2)$, $h=(x+3)^3, h'=3(x+3)^2$.  Assemble and win.

Comment: Thanks -- "assemble and win" haha.

Quick note: the answer provided in the text shows no addition, so the plot thickens....

Comment: @drzaius7 The answer vadim123 gives is easily factorised into the answer given in the text book.

Answer (score 5):

There is also the logarithmic differentiation approach: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation

Note that $\ln((x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^3)=\ln(x+1)+2\ln(x+2)+3\ln(x+3)$.

Then $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x))=\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)}$ using the chain rule.

So take the derivative of the RHS (above) to get

$$\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{2}{x+2}+\frac{3}{x+3}$$

Finish by multiplying both sides of the equation by the original function:

\begin{align*}f^\prime(x) &= f(x)\left(\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{2}{x+2}+\frac{3}{x+3}\right) \\
&= (x+2)^2(x+3)^3 + 2(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)^3 + 3(x+1)(x+2)^2(x+3)^2
\end{align*}

Comment: This method works nicely when your original function is the product of many thing.  The more things it is the product of, the nicer this approach becomes.

Comment: However, in general, you want to avoid this method for logarithms of negative numbers, because then $\log$ becomes multivalued.

Comment: It works especially well when there are *quotients* involved. Then the terms in the denominator are subtracted.

Comment: @martycohen, true.  I tend to view quotients as terms of a product with negative exponents...

Comment: I totally agree with you to such a point that I always wondered why we need  $(uv)'=\cdots$, $(\frac uv)'=\cdots$. Moreover, when programing, it is the less expensive manner for getting the derivative of products or quotients of complex expressions.